# Divide Matrix into Higher and Lower Value than Scalar Value Input

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, sum, divide

I have some problem in matlab since I was new in this programming language. Okay here it is :

I have `Matrix` and I have sorted it ascending, for example :

```
1
1
1
3
4
4
4
5
6
6
7
7
9
9
9
9
9
```

It's only 1 column matrix. I want to divide the matrix into two groups with some scalar value. Is I choose 5 as the scalar so my matrix will be divide into two groups higher than 5 and lower than 5 :

Expected result :

Lower Matrix :

```
1
1
1
3
4
4
4
5
```

Higher Matrix :

```
6
6
7
7
9
9
9
9
9
```

I have tried using `max` and `min` command but this command keep the matrix size and replace all lower number than scalar (5) into 5. Its a problem since for the next step I want to sum each lower and higher matrix.

Could you suggest me some trick?
Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use logical addressing to do this:

```
LowValuesMatrix = Matrix(Matrix <= 5);
HighValuesMatrix = Matrix(Matrix > 5);

LowValuesMatrix =
 1
 1
 1
 3
 4
 4
 4
 5

HighValuesMatrix =
 6
 6
 7
 7
 9
 9
 9
 9
 9
```